# Как записать в свойство объекта массив из объектов, где значениями будут являться значения массива?

Tags: javascript

Есть массив городов this.state.cities
И есть объект options

Как записать в свойство объекта city массив из объектов, где значениями будут являться значения массива this.state.cities

```
     const options = {
             city: [{city: 'vjvv'}, {city: 'fehfehfehe'}, {city: 'fjfehufehfe'}],
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.state.cities.map(function(x) { return {city:x} }) }
```

Вернет массив объектов с заданной структурой.